# Единственное или множественное число

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

И тут в дверях появились ещё двое в камуфляжной форме, только в фуражках вместо касок и без винтовок, с одними кобурами на поясе (на поясах?).

Какая форма правильная?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть использовано как единственное, так и множественное число

> Под утро в комнате стали появляться охотники в красных фраках и в ботфортах, с арапниками, с черными жокейскими шапочками, другие в зеленых бархатных кафтанах, с медными трубами **на поясе**... М. А. Алданов.

.

> Я открыл дверь. В комнату быстро вошли три человека с пистолетами **на поясах**. А. А. Бек

Преимущественно используют множественное число. В некоторых случаях использование единственного числа позволяет избежать двусмысленности, как в случае с парными объектами. Ср.:

> Два комиссара с маузерами на **боку**.
>
> Два комиссара с маузерами на **боках**.

В втором случае создается впечатление, что у каждого было по два маузера.